# File downloading without extension Socket Programming

Tags: c++, sockets, httpresponse

I am working in socket programming with help of C++.And I have to write a code to download file.
My Http Header for this is :

```
   char header[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel;Content-Disposition:attachment;filename:\"abc.xls\";Content-Length:14; \r\n\r\n";
```

but file get downloaded as "download" it does not have extension too.
I also tried this with

```
  char header[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:application/octet-stream;Content-Disposition:attachment;filename:\"abc.xls\";Content-Length:14; \r\n\r\n";
```

but its not working.
Can anyone help me regarding this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP response header you've tried looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel;Content-Disposition:attachment;filename:"abc.xls";Content-Length:14;
```

instead it should look like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="abc.xls"
Content-Length:14
```

I recommend you study the relevant standards before trying to implement a protocol. In this case this is the HTTP standard ([RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and following RFC) and "Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in the
Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)" ([RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)).

Comment: Hi I tried this but it didnt worked :
 char header[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel\r\nContent-Disposition:attachment;filename:\"abc.xls\"\r\nContent-Length:14 \r\n\r\n";

Comment: @Varun: please look closer at the example I've gave. It must be `filename=` and not `filename:`. And you should really make yourself familiar with standards instead of just fiddling around.